# Failing to install node on kali linux

Tags: node.js, linux, git

following thees steps to install node js from git . I am running kali linux 2016

```
# this way is best if you want to stay up to date
# or submit patches to node or npm

mkdir ~/local
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

# could also fork, and then clone your own fork instead of the official one

git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install
cd ..

git clone git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
make install # or `make link` for bleeding edge
```

I have not sucessfully installed npm. Becuase the error is that command

```
node
```

is not found. But i successfully installed node.
even echoed the path. What could be the problem

Comment: Kali linux is for penetration testing, it is not a general purpose GNU/Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Pre-Compiled Binaries :

[Download NodeJS v8.4.0 (x64 Linux)](https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.4.0/node-v8.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz)

extract `.tar.xz` > `/opt/node` (for example) and create a simbolic link for usage :

```
ln -s /opt/node/bin/node /usr/bin/node
ln -s /opt/node/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```